# Editor template for Nullables not working with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

All of my templates are working for non nullable value type. When the value type is a nullable though, Editor will use the template for strings instead.

This is my code:

Decimal.cshtml

```
@model Nullable<decimal>
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
        new { @class = "form-control validateFloat", placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark })
```

Object.cshtml

```
@foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties
    .Where(p => p.ShowForEdit)) {
    if ((prop.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("DoNotAutoGenerate")) ||
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prop.DataTypeName) && prop.Model is IEnumerable<object>))
    {
        // Do not generate  
    } 
    else if (prop.TemplateHint == "HiddenInput")
    {
        @Html.Hidden(prop.PropertyName)
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelLocalized(prop, ViewData.ModelMetadata, mgr)         
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @if(ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsPrimaryKey(prop))
                {
                    @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName, "ReadOnly")
                }else
                {                    
                    @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName, prop.DataTypeName) <-- This line calls String.cshtml instead of Decimal.cshtml when the data type is Nullable<decimal>. When the data type is decimal, the right template (Decimal.cshtml) is called.
                    @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName)
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

ProductDefinitionViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Infrastructure.Attributes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using ERPInterface;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using InventoryInterface;

namespace WebUI.ViewModels
{
    public class ProductDefinitionViewModel
    {
        //public ProductDefinitionViewModel()
        //{
        //    AttachedProductDefinitions = new List<AttachedProductDefinition>();
        //    ReplacementProductDefinitions = new List<ReplacementProductDefinition>();
        //}

        [DataType("ReadOnly")]
        public int ProductDefinitionId { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public Translation NameTranslation { get; set; }
        public string InternalId { get; set; }
        public string ExternalId { get; set; }

        [DataType("UnitOfMeasurementId")]
        public int UnitOfMeasurementId { get; set; }
        [DataType("Taxes")]
        public List<InventoryInterface.ProductDefinitionTax> ProductDefinitionTaxes { get; set; }

        [AdditionalMetadata("DoNotAutoGenerate", true)]
        public int NameTranslationId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<InventoryInterface.ProductDefinitionCode> ProductDefinitionCodes { get; set; }
        [DataType("ProductDefinitionNatures")]
        public Nullable<int> ProductDefinitionNatureId { get; set; }

        public bool FixedWeight { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Weight { get; set; } <-- Calls String template instead of Decimal template
        public Nullable<decimal> MinWeight { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> MaxWeight { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> PackagingWeight { get; set; }

        [DataType("Categories")]
        public Nullable<int> CategoryId { get; set; }
        [DataType("ProductDefinitionGroups")]
        public Nullable<int> ProductDefinitionGroupId { get; set; }   

        public List<AttachedProductDefinition> AttachedProductDefinitions { get; set; }
        public List<ReplacementProductDefinition> ReplacementProductDefinitions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What is missing so that the function Editor calls the decimal template instead of the string template?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most satisfactory solution, but probably the easiest: use the `UIHint` data annotation on your model property. e.g.:

```
[UIHint("Decimal")]
public Nullable<decimal> Weight { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, since I have a ton of models, I'm trying to find a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the model type with question mark(`decimal?`) instead of `Nullable<decimal>`